# nginx "413 Request Entity Too Large" (yes I checked various things.. see below)

Tags: docker, nginx, alpine-linux

Error message I am getting:

```
<html>
<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

1. I have a container based on image created like below:

   ```
   FROM nginx:alpine
   COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
   ```
2. Now inside the nginx.conf file I have the below settings:
   client_max_body_size 100M;
   Note that I tried changing the location of this setting in http, location, and server blocks.
   The issue still remained unsolved with that.
3. I am trying to upload an image of less than 10mb while the setting shows 100M above;

I did check that the Nginx configuration file inside the container shows the settings I mentioned above. I also did run nginx -t to view the current configuration file being used and if it is valid. It shows all clear here as well.

What am I missing ?

Note that I cannot reload the nginx service since that seems not allowed for containers created using the image above (FROM nginx:alpine) . Or is there a way I can reload the Nginx service for containers created using that image?
Note that I tried

```
rc-service nginx reload
rc-service nginx restart
sudo systemctl reload nginx
sudo service nginx start
```

All of them did not manage to restart the service

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Has below error:

```
ifquery: could not parse /etc/network/interfaces
* ERROR: networking failed to start
* ERROR: cannot start nginx as networking would not start
```

Comment: Change the config in the `nginx.conf` of your host. Stop your container, rebuild the image, start it again. That's the way with images and containers, they represent a state, if the state changes, you have to have a new image

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new image of your running container with your changes inside.

Create a new image of the running container with `docker run commit`

`$ docker commit [RUNNING_CONTAINER_ID] [MY_NEW_IMAGE_NAME]`

Stop the container and delete it

Run your new image with the changes now.